# How do I create a data frame with greek symbols as the column names?

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to build a data frame with greek letters as the column names, but using expression() does not seem to work.

I create the data frame like so:

```
random_parameter<-rep(c(0,.5,1),3)
radiusCluster_parameter<-rep(c(100,300,600),each=3)
Cluster_metric<-rep(NA,length(radiusCluster_parameter))
parameter_table<-data.frame(random_parameter,radiusCluster_parameter,Cluster_metric)
colnames(parameter_table)<-c("R", expression(rho),expression(sigma))
```

But this creates a data frame with the column names "R","rho" and "sigma". I'd prefer the actual "R", "ρ" and "σ".

Comment: Is this for printing purposes?

Comment: Eventually, it is also for visualisation before printing.

Comment: Maybe using `intToUtf8()`? For example, `colnames(parameter_table)<-c("R", intToUtf8(0x03C1), intToUtf8(0x03C3))`? Not very convenient though...

Comment: If it's for printing, the solution would likely depend in part on the package you're formatting your tables with and your final output format.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the greek character set so it can read the greek letters

```
Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_ALL", locale = "Greek")
```